# C# Memory Allocation & Linked List Implementation

Tags: c#, algorithm, memory, memory-management, linked-list

I have some questions about how exactly C# implement the linked list class
first question:

```
public class Node {  
    int data;  
    Node next;   
}
```

it looks like the rather than a linked list, it is a Big object with recursive same class inside

my second question is more specific, for a simple reverse linked list algorithm like below:

```
 public void ReverseList(ref ListNode head){
    if(head ==null || head.next == null) return head;
    ListNode cur = head;
    ListNode prev = null;
    ListNode next = head.next;
    while (cur != null){
        ListNode nextNode = head.next;
        cur.next= prev;
        prev=cur;
        cur=nextNode;
    }
    head = prev ;
}
```

isn't cur = head means the "cur" copy ALL  linked list elements?
And it is much harder to think what was going on in the algorithm.

Comment: I've implemented one here including `Reverse()` https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138142/linked-list-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linked list uses references to create the list structure.

The key point is to understand the distinction between **value** and **reference** types in C#. Value types like `int`, `bool` or `struct` are really values that are stored in stack and when you assign them, you are actually copying the data from one location to another. Reference types are `classes` in C# and the distinction is that they are just pointers to data in memory heap. By default, they are `null` and you first must allocate memory for them on the heap so that they actually point somewhere using `new`.

In this case you have a field of type `Node` as a property of the `Node` class, which is fine, because this is either just `null` or it points to another location in memory heap where the next node is stored. If you changed the `class` to `struct`, this would not compile, as this would cause the "recursive" problem you are mentioning. But with classes it is just a reference and the default value is `null`, so it **doesn't have to point to an instance** and instantiating a `Node` creates just one `Node` instance in memory, with `next == null`.

This should help you understand the second question as well - setting `next = head` means you are just making `next` point to the same place `head` is pointing in memory. You are not moving any data, you are just setting the reference.

[image: Linked list]

I find it helpful to use images when building linked list algorithms. you can imagine each `next` field just as an arrow that points somewhere. And when the value is `null` it just points "nowhere". Finally, when you assign something to `next` you just change where the arrow points.

Comment: Hi, for example ListNode A, if i have another statement ListNode B =A, does that mean Any changes in A will be reflected in B? So what to do if I just want an copy of A?

Comment: @朱嘉诚 you need to be *really really* careful with the terminology here; `B` and `A` are variables (that hold references), not objects. If `A` and `B` point point to the same object, then yes a change made to that object via `A` will be visible via `B`, but that's because there's only 1 object to talk about. When you say "just want an copy of A" - do you mean "a copy of the *reference*, i.e. the value of A" ? (that's easy: `B = A;`) - or do you mean "a copy of the *object* that A refers to" ? (that's harder; clone isn't a major theme in most .NET objects, although some have support for that)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

> it looks like the rather than a linked list, it is a Big object with recursive same class inside

`Node` is a `class`, which means that the field `Node next;` is a reference (broadly interchangeable with a pointer, in terms of terminology). So no: it is definitely a linked list. `Node` doesn't *contain* a `Node`. It contains a field which is a reference (think: pointer) to another `Node`.

> isn't cur = head means the "cur" copy ALL linked list elements?

It isn't copying *any* elements. It is changing the reference field (think: pointer) on some *existing* objects, and *that's it*. No copying. It is, however, *visiting* all the elements and changing the pointers on them all - so if you count "copying the references (think: pointers) on all elements": sure, it is doing that. There aren't any allocations involved, etc.

Comment: Hi, isn't that means if I change element in "cur", the "head" element is also changed? shouldn't "cur" be an independent object? suppose we let ListNode prev = Some Node and if the "cur" .next = prev , isn't that means cur.next is pointing to a new object?

Comment: @朱嘉诚 `cur` isn't an object *at all* - it is a local variable that holds a reference; the thing at the *end* of the reference is an object, sure. "isn't that means cur.next is pointing to a new object?" - it'll presumably be a *different* object; it isn't a *new* object

Comment: Thank you, it makes lots of sense, it's my first time asking question and i never expect answer to be this quick